# How to convert python url type to jquery object like document.body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, html2canvas

I'm trying to convert other websites (not in a same domain) to images with [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Since same-origin policy, I need to get the html at the back-end (which is coded with python). I get the response like this:

```
response = urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
```

The 'html' will then be passed to the front-end.

```
$("#read-test").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/atool/readurl',
        data: {url: "http://www.google.com"},
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        html2canvas($.parseHTML(data)).then(function(canvas) {
        });
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert('Failed.')
    })
});
```

The demo of html2canvas only converts a jquery object like document.body to a image (actually a canvas). That's why I $.parseHTML(data) in the above example. The problem is that there are lots of errors when trying to parse the html data.

How can I parse the url of the python to javascript document.body-like object?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're having a problem with? I don't understand what you mean by "How can I parse the url of they python to javascript document.body-like object". Do you want your server code to return only the `<body>` contents?

Comment: html2canvas works like this: html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {}), here I want to change 'document.body' to the 'data' the ajax returns. Since the 'data' is a string, it should be converted to a document.body-like object. I tried $.parseHTML(data) and $(data), both don't work. My question is how can I pass a document.body-like object to html2canvas function here?